# How to skip splitting for some part of the line

Tags: perl

Say I have a line `lead=george wife=jane "his boy"=elroy`. I want to split with space but that does not include the "his boy" part. I should be considered as one.

With normal split it is also splitting "his boy" like taking "his" as one and "boy" as second part. How to escape this

Following this i tried

```
split " ", $_
```

Just came to know that this will work

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $string = q(hi my name is 'john doe');
my @parts = $string =~ /'.*?'|\S+/g;
print map { "$_\n" } @parts;
```

But it does not looks good. Any other simple thing with split itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sub split_space {
  my ( $text ) = @_;

  while (
    $text =~ m/
      (               # group ($1)
        \"([^\"]+)\"  # first try find something in quotes ($2)
        |
        (\S+?)        # else minimal non-whitespace run ($3)
      )
      =
      (\S+)           # then maximum non-whitespace run ($4)
    /xg
  ) {
    my $key = defined($2) ? $2 : $3;
    my $value = $4;

    print( "key=$key; value=$value\n" );
  }
}

split_space( 'lead=george wife=jane "his boy"=elroy' );
```

Outputs:

```
key=lead; value=george
key=wife; value=jane
key=his boy; value=elroy
```

Comment: No need to escape double quotes inside a regex. Also, this does not allow for escaped quotes inside quoted strings.

Comment: @TLP valid comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Text::ParseWords](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Text-ParseWords-3.29/ParseWords.pm) for this

```
 use Text::ParseWords;

$list = "lead=george wife=jane \"his boy\"=elroy";

@words = quotewords('\s+', 0, $list);
  $i = 0;
  foreach (@words) {
      print "$i: <$_>\n";
      $i++;
  }
```

ouput:

```
0: <lead=george>
1: <wife=jane>
2: <his boy=elroy>
```

Answer (score 0):

PP posted a good solution. But just to make it sure, that there is a cool other way to do it, comes my solution:

```
my $string = q~lead=george wife=jane "his boy"=elroy~;

my @split = split / (?=")/,$string;
my @split2;
foreach my $sp (@split) {
  if ($sp !~ /"/) {
    push @split2, $_ foreach split / /, $sp;
  } else {
    push @split2,$sp;
  }
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @split2;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = 'lead=george';
$VAR2 = 'wife=jane';
$VAR3 = '"his boy"=elroy';
```

I use a Lookahead here for splitting at first the parts which keys are inside quotes `" "`. After that, i loop through the complete array and split all other parts, which are normal `key=values`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required result using a single regexp, which extract the keys and the values and put the result inside a hash table.

(\w+|"[\w ]+") will match both a single and multiple word in the key side.
The regexp captures only the key and the value, so the result of the match operation will be a list with the following content: key #1, value #1, key #2, value#2, etc.

The hash is automatically initiated with the appropriate keys and values, when the match result is assigned to it.

here is the code

```
my $str = 'lead=george wife=jane "hello boy"=bye hello=world';

my %hash = ($str =~ m/(?:(\w+|"[\w ]+")=(\w+)(?:\s|$))/g);

## outputs the hash content
foreach $key (keys %hash) {
  print "$key => $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

and here is the output of this script

```
lead => george
wife => jane
hello => world
"hello boy" => bye
```